Collecting page data ..Error: Cannot find module 'next/dist/client/components/static-generation-async-storage.external.js' Require stack:
This error is occurring when I am doing next build on my Next.js 14.2.3 project.
I am running my project on a MacOS machine locally.
package.json
  "name": "mydeen-waitlist",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@neondatabase/serverless": "^0.10.4",
    "email-validator": "^2.0.4",
    "lucide-react": "^0.469.0",
    "next": "15.1.2",
    "react": "^19.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^19.0.0",
    "react-hot-toast": "^2.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@eslint/eslintrc": "^3",
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^19",
    "@types/react-dom": "^19",
    "eslint": "^9",
    "eslint-config-next": "15.1.2",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.1",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
}

next info
  Platform: darwin
  Arch: arm64
  Version: Darwin Kernel Version 24.2.0: Fri Dec  6 18:51:28 PST 2024; root:xnu-11215.61.5~2/RELEASE_ARM64_T8112
  Available memory (MB): 8192
  Available CPU cores: 8
Binaries:
  Node: 23.4.0
  npm: 11.0.0
  Yarn: N/A
  pnpm: 9.15.0
Relevant Packages:
  next: 14.2.3 // An outdated version detected (latest is 15.1.2), upgrade is highly recommended!
  eslint-config-next: N/A
  react: 18.3.1
  react-dom: 18.3.1
  typescript: 5.3.3
Next.js Config:
  output: N/A
 ⚠ An outdated version detected (latest is 15.1.2), upgrade is highly recommended!
   Please try the latest canary version (`npm install next@canary`) to confirm the issue still exists before creating a new issue.
   Read more - https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/opening-an-issue```

